# Convert Unix Epoch Time to Date in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, epoch

I have a sheet with a column of unix epoch times (in seconds): 1500598288

How can I convert these into normal dates?

Comment: As what time zone will the sheet display this date? Does it differ on what user opens it?

Answer (score 207):

As of 2023, GSheet introduced a new function, `EPOCHTODATE`:

```
=EPOCHTODATE(1500598288)
```

To convert a whole column of numbers, just use `ARRAYFORMULA` (or `BYROW`, if you are `LAMBDA`-inclined):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(EPOCHTODATE(A:A))
```

[image]

*--- The answer below still works, but is outdated as of 2023 ---*

*The simplest way, not requiring any JS programming, would be through a formula, dividing by 86400 seconds per day and adding to January 1, 1970. For example the following gives 21 July 2017:*

```
=1500598288 / 86400 + DATE(1970, 1, 1)
```

*To convert a whole column of numbers, just use `ARRAYFORMULA`:*

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A / 86400 + DATE(1970, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Also, Unix time is UTC(Coordinated Universal Time). Considering your time zone, for example, I'm in San Francisco, it would be

Comment: please amend typo in number of seconds:
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/cXhne_Ys_QU/un3q9nVR3qMJ

Comment: Hi @lbrutti, what exactly are you referring to? What is the typo?

Comment: It's 2017 and Google, the land of the power users, don't think anyone wants to convert timestamps to human readable dates in a spreadsheet. I must be living in the wrong universe.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat. If you have clients that want to peruse your spreadsheet and have no idea what a unix timestamp is.

Comment: Nice!! And the reverse is: `=(B71-date(1970,1,1))*86400`

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos what would B71 mean in this case? the cell with date data?

Comment: @Shaardool , yes the cell with the data!

Comment: A simple copy-paste of your formula gives me #ERROR in google sheets.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia What is the error's details when you hover over it? This formula is so simple that it's hard to imagine how it can fail... maybe you placed it in the A column itself, which contains the data, then it would be a circular reference.

Comment: @ttarchala it is not a circular reference and it just says the formula is wrong, this one works tho: A2/60/60/24 + DATEVALUE("1970/1/1")

Comment: Useful to note here is that, if you want to convert a Unix timestamp to your own timezone, you should also add `time(1, 0, 0)` to go to UTC+1, or subtract `time(1, 0, 0)` to go to UTC-1, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Two additions for it to work for me: my timestamp was text, so I needed to convert with `VALUE()`, and the timestamp had milliseconds, so `/ 1000 `, like: `=arrayformula(VALUE(A:A) / 86400 / 1000 + date(1970,1,1))`

Comment: how do you format this to show as a date?

Comment: @dcsan Just use the usual formatting button "123▼" on the Sheets toolbar.

Comment: @ttarchala For languages that use comma as a decimal separator, the parameters should be separated by semicolons.

Comment: @LHLaurini Of course, but this is not specific to the question or to the answer - it's true for all formulas and people who write any formula are expected to know this already.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to tag @IgnacioSolerGarcia, since that's probably why it wasn't working for them

Answer (score 46):

Make a custom function using the javascript [Date function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

Tools > Script Editor... >

```
function FROM_UNIX_EPOCH(epoch_in_secs) {
  return new Date(epoch_in_secs * 1000);  // Convert to milliseconds
}
```

And then in a new column you can do `=FROM_UNIX_EPOCH(A1)`

Comment: Note that you now need a JSDoc comment with @customfunction in order for your script to be usable in the sheet. Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 13):

Add this for Epoch Timestamp to DateTime (GMT adjustment) in google sheets cell

=A1/86400+DATE(1970,1,1)+time(5,30,0)

Comment: simple and it works. thank you!!!

Answer (score 12):

now, 3 years later from the original post, you can make...

Tools > Script Editor... >

```js
function millisToDate(timeInMillis){
    var yourDateFromMillis = new Date(timeInMillis);
    return yourDateFromMillis;
}
```

and use your new function in the cell...

`=millisToDate(cell here)`

Comment: I use the above function a lot. 

I'm adding some bonus items here. :) 

You can set to locale time also. For example: 


function millisToDate(timeInMillis){
    var yourDateFromMillis = new Date(timeInMillis).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' });
    return yourDateFromMillis;
}

Timezones are here. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: this answer works in google sheets, while the FROM_UNIX_EPOCH() above does not.

Comment: This is not working for me. If I use:

1665578823 / Wed Oct 12 2022 12:47:03 GMT+0000

The value in the sheet is 20/01/1970

Answer (score 8):

Building on the accepted answer, you will want to use FLOOR() if you want to be able to compare the dates

```
=FLOOR(1500598288/86400)+date(1970,1,1)
```

Otherwise, "7/21/2017" in one cell might not equal "7/21/2017" in another cell.

Answer (score 5):

Building on the other awesome answers, here's what I use to get the full date time from an epoch timestamp. Tested with Google Sheets.

```
=QUOTIENT(A1, 86400) + date(1970, 1, 1) + time(quotient(MOD(A1, 86400), 3600), quotient(mod(A1, 3600), 60), mod(A1, 60))
```

Some examples:

| epoch | date time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1970-01-01 0:00:00 |
| 61 | 1970-01-01 0:01:01 |
| 3599 | 1970-01-01 0:59:59 |
| 86403 | 1970-01-02 0:00:03 |
| 2678402 (=86400*31+2) | 1970-02-01 0:00:02 |
| 31536008 (=86400*365+8) | 1971-01-01 0:00:08 |

Answer (score 1):

In AppScript Paste this :

```
function EpocToDate(epoch) {
  //var epoch = 1451606400000; 12/31/2015 19:00:00
  return (Utilities.formatDate(new Date (epoch),'America/New_York','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'));
}
```

Use in Google Sheets as:

```
=EpocToDate(1451606400000)
```

Incase if you have to refer from another cell :

```
=EpocToDate(VALUE(C2))
```

Answer (score -7):

The formula given in the answer by ttarchala is incorrect. Here is a more expansive answer.

I'd recommend not replacing the data in the of seconds since epoch times column. You may need it for sorting, etc. Additionally, it will be difficult to apply the formula to an entire column. Instead, initially insert a new column next to it.

Click in the new cell adjacent the topmost epoch cell. Assuming that the topmost epoch cell is A1, enter this formula into the formula box for the new cell.

```
=A1/8640000+date(1970,1,1)
```

The date time should be displayed in your new cell. By default, it will only show the date and not the time. To make it show the time as well you need to change the cell format. With your new date cell selected, click the 123 format drop down menu and select the required cell format.

To apply this formula to all of the cells in the column, click the small black square (handle) at the bottom right of the date / time cell and drag  it to the bottom of the column. Once you release the drag the columns should be populated with the date time conversion for its adjacent epoch data cell. You can see the epoch data cell index changed in the formula as you select each cell separately.

Comment: Would you be able elaborate on where exactly my answer is incorrect?

Comment: Also, my answer is trivially easy to apply to an entire column with the use of =ARRAYFORMULA().

Comment: I'm afraid too that it's your answer which is incorrect -- the OP is asking to convert the time in _seconds_, and so the time should be divided by 86,400 seconds per day. Why are you telling the OP to divide by 8,640,000?