# How to convert time for G Sutie Reseller API from number to exact date?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Due to G Suite Reseller API: Manage subscriptions. Reference as below link.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_subscriptions

When I call `startDate` and `EndDate` it will show as an integer number as below:

```
"startTime": "1331647980142",
"endTime": "1363183980142"
```

Does anyone have a good idea for how to convert it to be an exact date (i.e. 03-Oct-2019)?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to solve this issue few minutes ago. Following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227380/convert-unix-epoch-time-to-date-in-google-sheets), You can use formula like this below to convert epoch time to exact date.

```
=yourepochtime/86400000+date(1970,1,1)
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same issue.