# Convert Hubspot NIX-like integer date to Google Sheets human readable date

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, epoch, hubspot

I have read multiple articles for this question and none of them answers my question properly:
[Convert Unix Epoch Time to Date in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227380/convert-unix-epoch-time-to-date-in-google-sheets) | 
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108115/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-human-readable | 
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-sheets/google-sheets-convert-unix-epoch-timestamp-to-date/

I have a date from Hubspot Sales for which I use a zap to connect to Google Sheets. From Hubspot I get a date `1574842022157` which I try to convert according to the main idea in those articles which say that an epoch date `1500598288` should be formatted with `=1500598288/86400+date(1970,1,1)` resulting in a date.

When I try that (after changing the updated syntax for the date function in my locale to be) `=1500598288/86400+datum(1970;1;1)` I get the result `2017-07-21`, when using the example date of `1500598288`.

When using the Hubspot date `1574842022157` the result is completely different. Just by doing the first division without adding the traditional date from 1970 I get the date of `51804-10-02`. As I understand Google Sheets uses 30 November 1899 as its zero-date, so it makes no sense to add more than 70 years to my date by using the part `+datum(1970;1;1)` in my date which is already too far into the future.

The peculiar thing is that when I give my Hubspot date of `1574842022157` to the converter at https://www.epochconverter.com/ it returns the date `Wednesday 27 November 2019 09:07:02.157 GMT+01:00`, which is correct.

So what is that converter doing that all the helpful articles linked to at the top are missing? On the converter page https://www.epochconverter.com/ you are able to read that:

`Human-readable time    Seconds
1 hour                  3600 seconds
1 day                   86400 seconds
1 week                  604800 seconds
1 month (30.44 days)    2629743 seconds
1 year (365.24 days)    31556926 seconds`

A curiosity is that if I divide my date with the amount of seconds in a year in a Google Sheet cell I get closer to my date, but it's still not correct.

`1574842022157 / 31556926 = 2036-08-17`

So is it a case of just manually finding the respective offset for when dividing either with the seconds of a day alternatively with the seconds of a year respectively, or is there a smart mechanism at work here which is easier to make work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found the answer here http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/datetimeepoch

where the formula given everywhere else of `numeric datetime / the seconds in a day = numeric datetime / 86400 = numeric datetime / (60*60*24) = numeric datetime / 60/60/24` before adding the epoch date of 1970-01-01 is incorrect when it comes to my problem.

Instead it should be replaced with `numeric datetime /1000/60/60/24` and when you add the epoch date of 1970-01-01 to the result of that calculation you get the accurate date. So the formula that answers my problem is then

`numeric datetime/1000/60/60/24+DATUM(1970;1;1)`

In my Google Sheets cell the formula looks like `=G3/1000/60/60/24+DATUM(1970;1;1)` where `G3 = 1574842022157`.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that your epoch time is in milliseconds instead of seconds, therefore:

```
=A1/86400000+DATE(1970; 1; 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for that explanation and reminder! I saw that text, but ignored it, since I was too early in my explorations when I saw it, and then when it actually became relevant I had forgotten it was there. Great clarification! =)

Comment: are you saying that you want credit for your answer? Very well, if it is that important to you, I will do that for the sake of your clarification, now that I found an answer to my problem myself. =)